# Formidable After Create Entry

Tags: php, hook, formidable

Is anyone here trying to use the `frm_after_create_entry` hook by Formidable Pro ?

I'm currently trying to use it in order to send form data to a distant PHP script. Here is my code for now, placed in the header.php of the theme i'm using :

```
 add_action('frm_after_create_entry', 'yourfunctionname', 30, 2);
 function yourfunctionname($entry_id, $form_id){
     $args = array();
     if(isset($_POST['item_meta'][64]))
         $args['data1'] = $_POST['item_meta'][64];
     if(isset($_POST['item_meta'][65]))
         $args['data2'] = $_POST['item_meta'][65];
     $result = wp_remote_post('http://192.168.1.XXX/interface/index.php', (array('body' => $args)));
}
```

But when I submit my form, there is nothing about data sending to my script..

Answer (score 3):

Formidable won't handle any response from the destination server, it will just send the payload. It seems more likely that the script on the other end isn't processing the payload correctly. Have you checked the logs on the destination server?

Also, you should move this to your theme's functions.php file, rather than have it in the header.